# Returning API response with token authorisation in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, api, authorization

I am using a form in wordpress to call a third party api and looking to filter the response in the confirmation text after submission. I have managed to do it on apis where no token authorisation is required by using e.g. this in my functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'gform_confirmation_4', 'custom_confirmation', 10, 4 );
function custom_confirmation( $confirmation, $form, $entry, $ajax ) {
$response = wp_remote_get( 'https://api.github.com/users/someuser' );

if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
echo 'An error happened';
} else {
$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
$data = json_decode( $body );
}

$confirmation .= print_r( $data->id, true );
return $confirmation;

}
```

Which returns the "id" value for that github user from the json and prints it in the confirmation.

For my restricted api which needs an authorisation token first, I place this in the functions.php

```
add_filter( 'gform_webhooks_request_headers_4', function ( $request_headers ) {
$token = GFCache::get( 'accessToken' );

if ( ! $token ) {
    $post_url = 'https://MyRestrictedApi.com/v1/auth/accesstokenrequest? 
name=something&password=something';
    $headers  = array( 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-url-form-encoded' );

    $response = wp_remote_post( $post_url, array( 'body' => $body, 'headers' => $headers ) );
    gf_webhooks()->log_debug( 'gform_webhooks_request_headers: response => ' . print_r( $response, 
true ) );

    if ( ! is_wp_error( $response ) && wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response ) == 200 ) {
        $response_body_json  = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
        $response_body_array = json_decode( $response_body_json, true );

        if ( isset( $response_body_array['accessToken'] ) ) {
            $token = $response_body_array['accessToken'];
            GFCache::set( 'accessToken', $token, true, $response_body_array['expires_in'] - 30 );
        }
    }
}

if ( $token ) {
    gf_webhooks()->log_debug( 'gform_webhooks_request_headers: token added.' );
    $request_headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' . $token;
}

return $request_headers;
} );
```

This issues the token correctly as I can see it works in the form debugging logs and shows the api response data from the form submission inside the logs.

I have been trying to combine an equivalent of these two code blocks to get the response printed on the confirmation of the form when calling the restricted api, which replaces the github demo used above with the below.

```
add_filter( 'gform_confirmation_4', 'custom_confirmation', 10, 4 );
function custom_confirmation( $confirmation, $form, $entry, $ajax ) {
$response = wp_remote_get( 'https://MyRestrictedAPI.com/v1/user/list' );

if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
echo 'An error happened';
} else {
$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
$data = json_decode( $body );
}

$confirmation .= print_r( $data->id );
return $confirmation;

}
```

But the result is it prints "1" on the confirmation (maybe the ssl true value), whereas the "id" 8864 would be expected. Looking at the form's debugging logs shows:

```
(
[body] => 
[method] => GET
[headers] => Array
    (
        [Authorization] => Bearer 9kcTI3DEChPHgRr3kheHqnGaiBqaeT7MzIQUCZwM-5KLuLpZxL...
    )

[sslverify] => 1
)

2020-01-06 9:29:10.110383 - DEBUG --> GF_Webhooks::process_feed(): Webhook successfully executed. 
code: 200; body: [{"id":8864,"name": etc...
```

Do I need to take the accessToken into the second function in my functions.php, is this why it is not getting the response printed? Any tips on how to do that? Thanks

Comment: the `1` comes from "print_r", try with `$confirmation = $data[0]->id;`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it fails to bring the id. The print_r( $data->id, true ); works for the first github demo with an open api so thinking it's an authorisation issue in functions.php